# How to multi condition left join with Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the DQL like this:

```
    $sql = $qb->select('
                c.login             
            ,   c.id 
            ,   i.count                     
            ')
            ->from('customer','c')
            ->leftJoin(__NAMESPACE__ .'\\'.'Item','i','WITH','c.id = i.owner_id')               
            ->where('c.login = :login')->setParameter('login',$login)               
            ->groupBy('
                c.id                
            ,   c.login
            ,   i.count 
            ')                      
            ;
```

I want to multi condition left join like this  in SQl:

```
SELECT 
        c.login             
        ,   c.id 
        ,   i.count  
 FROM
        Customer c
 LEFT JOIN
        Item i
 ON
        c.id = i.owner_id
 AND
        i.id = "adc" 
 WHERE 
        c.account = 'Personal'
 GROUP BY
            c.login             
        ,   c.id 
        ,   i.count
```

Could someone translate into `DQL` for me?
I can't let  `i.id = "adc"` in where because the left table data would not show all.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try `->leftJoin(__NAMESPACE__ .'\\'.'Item','i','WITH','c.id = i.owner_id AND i.id = "adc"');`

Comment: It works. I thought it was ->andLeftJoin() or else. Thanks  alot.

Comment: Glad. I could help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815869/doctrine2-left-join-with-2-conditions