# How to do advanced left join with doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'd like to translate the following request with the doctrine query builder :

```
SELECT *  
FROM t_prm_ad_administration AS r1  
LEFT JOIN t_prm_ad_administration AS r2  
    ON r1.exec_order > r2.exec_order  
    AND r1.filename = r2.filename
WHERE r2.id = :id
```

Is it possible with the doctrine query builder using leftJoin() ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do left join in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087933/how-to-do-left-join-in-doctrine)

Comment: Or https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-you-add-a-binding-when-using-dbraw-in-a-join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 LEFT JOIN with 2 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815869/doctrine2-left-join-with-2-conditions)